# Use local Wix Toolset in TFS

Tags: tfs, wix

Hi I want to build my Wix-Project on my TFS-Server.
I checked in a local copy of the wix-binaries - which are looking good.

Now i want to reference my local copy in my wix-v3-project like that:

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <WixToolPath>$(SourceCodeControlRoot)\wix\[[Version]]\</WixToolPath>
      <WixTargetsPath>$(WixToolPath)Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
      <WixTasksPath>$(WixToolPath)wixtasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It is described here: [Link](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/daily_builds.html)

But it tells me that - `WixToolPath` is an unknown node. So how can i reference my local wix toolset? And also what do i need to reference so that it can build only with my local copy on the toolset.

My main target is - to not change the tfs agent - to make wix working.

EDIT:

This is working in v4 - how can i achieve this in v3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think that's the right way to do this, avoid checking-in the binaries to source control when possible. Here is a list of steps that you can do:

1. Change the Nuget.config to point to your local Nuget repo. If your TFS agents have internet access and go to the nuget repo, then it can point to the web nuget repo as well.
2. Check-in the Nuget Config/Nuget.exe file to TFS (you can avoid this step, if you have access to the TFS agents or if you have Nuget on it already).
3. In your wix solution/project, add the WIX nuget package as a reference and then check-in those changes to TFS.
4. Within your build script, before you compile the wix project add a step to do the Nuget restore based on the packesg.config/wix solution file.

Comment: Wait a second - so i dont need a wix project?  I can just apply the wix-nuget package on a project it will build msi?

Comment: nope you do need a wixproj, the wix Nuget Package will be added as a reference to your wixproj file